# Flask-Security: user does not persist into database upon registeration

Tags: sqlite, flask, flask-security

User is able to register and confirm their mail but when the flask server is shut down and restarted, it no longer remembers any of the previous registered users, forcing people to sign up all over again.

How can I debug this? I am on ubuntu 12.04 server running flask-security.

I am using a local `SQLite` `.db` file

When I check the `.db`, the user seems to be there but disappears when the server is shut down completely and rebooted again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your app is destroying and recreating the database each time it's launched.  Do you have some code along the lines of `drop_all()` and `create_all()` in your app's initialization code?

Comment: there was a function that happens before app starts and that is create a user. once i removed this, it seems like the older users persist. it seems that creating a user was in fact starting a new slate and creating that single user:/